# iPhone - Is it ok to override UITableViewCell setSelected:animated

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview, quartz-graphics

I am drawing custom UITableViewCells.  My cells are opaque and are completely drawn in the drawRect of the cell to help with performance.  I want to handle the look of a selected cell myself.  If I don't, then the contents of my cell is covered up by the selectedBackgroundView that is added.  Is it common or acceptable to override the setSelected:animated method of my cell so this is done properly.  I guess if I did that, then I would not call the super's setSelected method since I would be handling how the cell will show that its selected.  I would also have to set the selected property of the cell.

Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can override `-[UITableViewCell setSelected:animated:]`, but you should always call the super's implementation in your implementation.  Not doing so could have have unanticipated effects on other selection-related behaviors.

If you don't want the superclass to make any styling changes as a result of the selection, just set the cell's `selectionStyle` property to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.